# Delete app intent not working on android pie

Tags: android, android-intent, android-9.0-pie

This worked in the past but does not work on my android pie device anymore (worked until the recent pie update):

```
fun uninstallApp(packageName: String) {
    val packageURI = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI)
    intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent )
}
```

I could not find any documentation that indicates that this intent is not working anymore.

Does anyone know if there is an alternative way to open the uninstall dialog on android pie?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The code will still work, supposedly the app is not requesting the permission to execute it.

Since Android Pie (Android 9), apps are required to declare that they request apps to be deleted. This can be done by adding this permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

** Note that it is not needed to request this permission at runtime. Declaring this in the Manifest is enough for it to work.*

---

Also, we could use the `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` action instead for the request of removing packages. For this action, the documentation is mentioning that the permission stated above is required for it to work since Android Pie.

Comment: Did not find this information when looking for the intent I use, but as you said, it's documented for the `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` intent. Thanks

Comment: Yea that's true. The *ACTION_DELETE* can also be used for deleting other things based on a URI scheme. Not sure, but that might be why it isn't mentioning this permission for that action in the documentation. Instead, the *ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE* is specific in what it does. Anyway, glad this solved it! Your welcome

Comment: I switched to using `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` as well, I use this function for this purpose only, so this change makes sense for me as well.

Comment: +1. Also observed that when the android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES permission is not declared in manifest, the startActivity on the uninstall intent neither shows any uninstall confirm dialog with ok/cancel buttons nor it throws any exception